# "Advanced" stratification of data in R

Tags: r, survival, stratification

I have a `data.frame` with a column `Material` that has 7 different codes for 7 different materials: `'AC', 'GGIJ', 'HPE', 'ONB', 'PE', 'PVC', 'ST'`

Is there a way to stratify my data considering two or more of these as equivalent (i.e. generating 6 levels instead of 7 because for example `'PVC'` is considered in the same level as `'PE'`)

Specifically I'm using this for survival analysis with the `survive` package. Trying to have more control on the `survdiff(formula = survObj ~ Material, data = data)` and `survfit(survObj ~ Material., data = data)` functions.

However, I see this also being useful for visualization or other types of data analysis.

I am aware I can do this by adding a column in the `data.frame`, but since I need to try different combinations, I'd love to do it on-the-fly.

Comment: I am not really sure what kind of advice your are expecting. Nevertheless, I'd like to mention the R package [forcats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forcats/index.html) that has functions for collapsing factor levels.

Comment: @hplieninger, sorry if my question ins't clear. However, the package you suggests seems to have the functionality I'm looking for! Thanks

Comment: Then, I add this as an answer, feel free to "accept" it.

Comment: This is a quesiton for StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, you are very right, I just realized it too late. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R package [forcats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forcats/index.html) has functions for collapsing factor levels, for example, `fct_collapse()`:

```
> tmp1 <- factor(letters[1:4])
> tmp1
[1] a b c d
Levels: a b c d
> forcats::fct_collapse(tmp1, x = c("a", "b", "c"))
[1] x x x d
Levels: x d
```